# TinyMCE dropdown arrows below buttons and buttons not working correctly

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I have downloaded TinyMCE V4.0.1 and really want to work with it. Unfortunately, when I use it, some things happen that should not happen:

- At the buttons that have a drop down (like the color button), the dropdown falls beneath the button
- When selecting a piece of text and for example pressing the **B** button to make it bold, the cursor jumps back to the start of the editor and nothing happens.

This is the code I'm using for the editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#fulltext_editor",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
    menubar: false,
    toolbar1: "save | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline subscript superscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify",
    toolbar2: "bullist numlist | forecolor backcolor | link image media | table | searchreplace | code"
});
```

Even with a more simple code the above points happen. I haven't found any explanation of why this should happen and how this would be resolved. Also, I can't get the jQuery version to work at all (I am using jQuery for other stuff on my website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem with the dropdowns, you have probably set the HTML `span` element to `display: block` somewhere in your CSS.  Add the following to fix it:

```
.mce-menubtn span {
  display: inline-block
}
```

In terms of the bold functionality not working, I can only imagine there is a JS conflict somewhere.  Is anything showing up in the JS Console when you load the page or click the button?